# Batch - Compare file date with actual date

Tags: date, batch-file, compare

I get the `file date` from a file:

```
for %%x in (%file_test%) do set file_date_test=%%~tx
```

And then I get the `system date`:

```
set year=%date:~-4%
set month=%date:~3,2%
if "%month:~0,1%" == " " set month=0%month:~1,1%
set day=%date:~0,2%
if "%day:~0,1%" == " " set day=0%day:~1,1%

set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
set min=%time:~3,2%
if "%min:~0,1%" == " " set min=0%min:~1,1%
```

And then do an `if statement` with `goto`:

```
IF %file_date_test% LSS %system_date_test% goto SOME
```

How can I compare both dates? I would like to check if the file date has **more than 24H**.

Which is the best way to do that? Can I use `forfiles` to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited** `forfiles` command will not even look at the hour of the file, so the previous answer (at the bottom in case someone find it useful) will not work if the file has different date but less than 24h.

For an alternative

```
robocopy "c:\backup" "c:\backup" "test.bak" /l /nocopy /is /minage:1 > nul 
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo MATCH
) else (
    echo NO_MATCH
)
```

At least in windows 7, the `robocopy` command look at the timestamp of the file to determine its age.

---

*Previous answer*

You can use `forfiles` checking the errorlevel of the operation

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "file_test=c:\backups\test.bak"

    for %%a in ("%file_test%") do (
        forfiles /p "%%~dpa." /m "%%~nxa" /d -1 >nul 2>nul && echo MATCH || echo NO MATCH
    )
```

Or

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    forfiles /p "c:\backups" /m "test.bak" /d -1 >nul 2>nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo NO_MATCH
    ) else (
        echo MATCH
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the meaning of the first line? `setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion`

Comment: @mac94, `setlocal` alone will ensure that changes to the environment variables will be discarded when the batch file ends (or `endlocal` is called), but is necessary to use the `enableextensions` and `disabledelayedexpansion`. It is a habit I have to always include them at the start of a batch file to ensure how the batch will behave. Sometimes people have extensions disabled and `for /f` (just an ex.) will not be available. Or `delayedexpansion` can be enabled and generate problems with `!`. I use to include the line just  to be sure what is the environment where the code runs.

Comment: I tried with the second way, and with a file from `27-04-2015` and it returns me `MATCH`but should return `NO_MATCH`

Comment: @mac94, as stated in the question. It is more than 24h old

Comment: Sorry, but `errorlevel 1` is like `older than 24h`? I don't understand that.

Comment: @mac94, `errorlevel 1` means `no file matching the conditions`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82493/discussion-between-mac94-and-mc-nd).